# SQL query based on condition

Tags: mysql, sql, resultset

**Use case**: I am working on a sql query for the below tables. I have 2 tables in my schema viz cropdetails and translationcropdetails. Cropdetails holds the basic common info and translationcropdetails holds the translations in multiple languages.

I am working on writing a query that would return a list of all records from translationcropdetails with language id =<**english_lang_id**> and also return in how many languages the record is present in the table.

```
   Example output:
   cropid  |  cropname    |    langid1(say eng)                           |    langid2(say spanish)          | langid3
      1       Wheat        true(if translation present for that language)   false(if translation not present)
```

I need direction in which I can move in writing this. I am not sure if I can go ahead with `case when` operator. Any inputs would be helpful in achieving the expected result.

```
 +--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
   | Field        | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
   +--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
   | cropid       | bigint(20)   | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
   | cropimage    | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
   | noofdays     | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
   +--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
      
   +-----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
    | Field           | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
   +-----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
   | trcropid        | bigint(20)   | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
   | cropadvice      | text         | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
   | cropattacks     | text         | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
   | cropdescription | text         | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
   | cropname        | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
   | cropid          | bigint(20)   | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
   | languageid      | bigint(20)   | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
   +-----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

I am using spring boot and this is a paging query that I will be executing as a native query.
Currently the below query will fetch only the list of records in english.

```
   @Query(value = "select cr.* from (select cr.trcropid, cr.cropname, cr.cropid, cr.languageid from "
        + "translationcropdetails cr where cr.languageid=:languageId) cr \n#pageable\n",
        countQuery = "select count(*) from (select cr.trcropid, cr.cropname, cr.cropid, cr.languageid from "
                + "translationcropdetails cr where cr.languageid=:languageId) temp", nativeQuery = true)
public Page<Object[]> getAllCrops(@Param("languageId") Long languageId, Pageable pageable);
```

Need the way to achieve the result as mentioned above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try with this query, which builds another query that will retreive the resultset you need. It seems a strange approach, but with MySQL is the only way to have the final query built dynamically, without know how many languages you have defined.

```
    SELECT CONCAT(
        'SELECT `translationcropdetails`.cropid', GROUP_CONCAT(', `t_', REPLACE(languageid, '`', '``'), '`.trcropid IS NOT NULL AS `lang_', REPLACE(languageid, '`', '``'), '`' SEPARATOR ''),
 ' FROM `translationcropdetails` ', GROUP_CONCAT('
     LEFT JOIN `translationcropdetails`   AS `t_', REPLACE(languageid, '`', '``'), '`
            ON `translationcropdetails`.cropid = `t_', REPLACE(languageid, '`', '``'), '`.cropid
           AND `t_', REPLACE(languageid, '`', '``'), '`.languageid = ', QUOTE(languageid)
     SEPARATOR ''),
 ' GROUP BY `translationcropdetails`.cropid'
) FROM (SELECT DISTINCT languageid FROM `translationcropdetails`) t;
```

and this is the query built from the previous one in case of 3 languages defined:

```
SELECT
    `translationcropdetails`.cropid,
    `t_1`.trcropid IS NOT NULL AS `lang_1`,
    `t_2`.trcropid IS NOT NULL AS `lang_2`,
    `t_3`.trcropid IS NOT NULL AS `lang_3`
FROM `translationcropdetails`
    LEFT JOIN `translationcropdetails` AS `t_1`
        ON `translationcropdetails`.cropid = `t_1`.cropid
        AND `t_1`.languageid = '1'
    LEFT JOIN `translationcropdetails` AS `t_2`
        ON `translationcropdetails`.cropid = `t_2`.cropid
        AND `t_2`.languageid = '2'
    LEFT JOIN `translationcropdetails` AS `t_3`
        ON `translationcropdetails`.cropid = `t_3`.cropid
        AND `t_3`.languageid = '3'
GROUP BY `translationcropdetails`.cropid;
```

You can see the result of the generated query in [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fa90fd/24/0) where I used the following dummy data:

```
-- languageid: 1 = English | 2 = Spanish | 3 = French | ...
INSERT INTO translationcropdetails VALUES
  (1, 'adv 1', 'att 1', 'english descr', 'name 1', 1, 1),
  (2, 'adv 1', 'att 1', 'español descr', 'name 1', 1, 2),
  (3, 'adv 2', 'att 2', 'eng descr', 'name 2', 2, 1),
  (4, 'adv 2', 'att 2', 'descr en français', 'name 2', 2, 3),
  (5, 'adv 3', 'att 3', 'eng descr', 'name 3', 3, 1),
  (6, 'adv 4', 'att 4', 'eng descr', 'name 4', 4, 1),
  (7, 'adv 5', 'att 5', 'español descr', 'name 5', 5, 2),
  (8, 'adv 5', 'att 5', 'descr en français', 'name 5', 5, 3)
 ;
```

The output will be

```
cropid  lang_1  lang_2  lang_3
------- ------- ------- -------
1       1       1       0
2       1       0       1
3       1       0       0
4       1       0       0
5       0       1       1
```

Comment: Will definitely try this and revert! Will need little formatting from my end, but this looks on point. Kudos!

Comment: Yes, @coderunner, you're absolutely right. It was simply difficult to format in this little editor :D This is my first answer...still have to improve ;)

Comment: @coderunner, if my answer solved your question, please, feel free to mark the answer as the accepted one :) Thanks

Comment: I have. Also, being your first answer this was very well explained with an example fiddle. Appreciate your contribution and keep it up.

Comment: Hello, I needed a small update in the earlier wuery. I had to add a column `cropname` in the `cropdetails` table and show that cropname in the result. I tried updating the existing query but failed. Would be great if you can have a look. I have updated the fiddle for schema changes http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/88cf7f/3

Comment: Hello @coderunner. The problem is due to the first JOIN, made with the ',' and not with an explicit JOIN. Change your query from `FROM translationcropdetails, cropdetails` to `FROM translationcropdetails INNER JOIN cropdetails ON translationcropdetails.cropid = cropdetails.cropid` and it will work :)

Comment: Had a question regarding the result. What determines the datatype of the `lang_1`,`lang_2`,`lang_3` columns? I wrote similar queries on different set of tables and in place it returns BIGINT and other it returns as INT.

Comment: It's really strange. The datatype shouldn't depends on the query, but on the datatype defined in the table. Could you please create a dbfiddle to make some tests on this particular case?

Comment: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/sNQZKaV3q2yxuNss7WJnkX/0  I created a DB fiddle here but couldnt find the datatype of the resultset. Also I am using MySQL 5.7 and run into the Group by constraint error as in this fiddle if you switch to `5.7`. I wanted to try the dynamic query but the query as is prints the subquery which needs to be executed. Can you update exactly how can it run completely standalone as I need to configure it in the spring jpa config.

Comment: @coderunner In MySQL 5.7, with the `only_full_group_by`, you need to put all your non-aggregated fields in the `GROUP BY` expression. I've forked your dbfiddle: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/igLsrSF16FnxqjJev7Cow8/0

Comment: Otherwise, you can disable it with SET GLOBAL sql_mode=(SELECT REPLACE(@@sql_mode,'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY',''));

Comment: Yes I got it working by updating `sql_mode`. I wanted  to work on the dynamic query as there will be languages added in future. I did get the stand alone to work as it printed the working query. Do we need to add a explicit execute command? Because then I am wondering how I can do it using spring jpa via code. Updated earlier fiddle for dynamic query http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/88cf7f/19

Comment: posted a new question, if you can have a look. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67677552/condition-based-query-to-filter-records-in-mysql-spring-boot-application