# Condition based query to filter records in Mysql spring boot application

Tags: mysql, sql, join, inner-join

Working on creating a conditional filter query for the following tables. Created a fiddle with data [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/mvyy1PJDYtPL4h7A7wivhH/4).

The result needs to be filtered on cropid and producttypeid. Default I need to show **all the** products in the product table. Then as the user choses values of producttype and crop the result needs to **filter** accordingly where language can be one of the languages from language table.

What I have tried is a plain query which fails due to the Many-to-Many relation between product and crop. A product can be associated with multiple products and vice versa.

SQL tried:

```
select t.productid,tp.trproductid ,t.productimage,tp.productname,t.producttypeid, p.crop_id 
from productdetails t 
inner join  translationproductdetails tp on 
     t.productid = tp.productid 
left join productcrop p on tp.productid =p.product_id 
where tp.languageid=3 
ORDER by t.productid ;
```

Language

```
                   +--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
                   | Field        | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
                   +--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
                   | languageid   | bigint(20)   | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
                   | inserttime   | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
                   | insertedby   | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
                   | insertedbyid | bigint(20)   | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
                   | updatetime   | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
                   | languagename | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
                   | shortcode    | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
                   +--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

cropdetails

```
              +-------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
               | Field             | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
               +-------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
               | cropid            | bigint(20)   | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
               | cropnameeng       | varchar(20)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
               | cropimage         | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
               | noofdays          | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
               | inserttime        | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
               | updatetime        | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
               | imagelastmodified | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
               +-------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Productdetails

```
     +----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
     | Field          | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
     +----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
     | productid      | bigint(20)   | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
     | inserttime     | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
     | updatetime     | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL    |                           |
     | productimage   | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
     | productnameeng | varchar(50)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
     | producttypeid  | bigint(20)   | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
     +----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

translationproductdetails

```
    +--------------------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
     | Field              | Type       | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
     +--------------------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
     | trproductid        | bigint(20) | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
     | productdescription | text       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
     | productname        | text       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
     | languageid         | bigint(20) | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
     | productid          | bigint(20) | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
     | inserttime         | datetime   | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
     | updatetime         | datetime   | YES  |     | NULL    |                                |
     +--------------------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

relation table productcrop

```
  +------------+------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
  | Field      | Type       | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
  +------------+------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
  | product_id | bigint(20) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |       |
  | crop_id    | bigint(20) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |       |
  +------------+------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

**Desired output** I want to write a single query which first fetches list of all products from translationproductdetials and later accepts filter parameters based on produtypeid and cropid.

```
   productid|trproductid|productimage       |productname                 
  ------+-----------+-------------------+----------------------------
    1|          1|Product/Img_1.png  |other                       |
    2|          4|Product/Img_2.jpeg |onion pesti panchaganga     |
```

I get the product list for all using plain `select *` on transproductdetials. Also filter on producttypeid is achievable as its present in the productdetails table. The challenge is to filter on cropid as its many-to-many relation with products. So in my default query tried above and in fiddle I get all mappings of a product to all crops.

Looking forward for suggestions to achieve the result.

Comment: show us your desired output as well.

Comment: @eshirvana updated the expected result

Comment: @eshirvana Let me know if the information is sufficient.